# how to set textview height dynamically using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, textview, storyboard

Need to setup a textview which will have 30 as its initial height [image]  like this

while user entering the text the textview height have to be increased till certain height

[image]

How can i achieve this using autolayout and this is how my autolayout constraints look like 
[image]

Comment: How the content resistance and content hugging is in scene ?  Your issue doesn't related to what you have put it in your title of your question

Comment: ok then is there any other method to achieve this by setting autolayout properties

Comment: You can have height constant IBOutlet and increase it as per contnet but less than maximum size you allowed

Comment: Your height is fixed. Try to remove the height and run it again.

Comment: use `pod 'GrowingTextView`

Comment: @MdRashedPervez if i remove height 30 my textview initial height become 100. need the textview height to be 30 at initial state and it have to be grow according to user input

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya i have tried this and got the solution but just want to know is there any other easy methods available

Comment: @MidhunNarayan For me it looks like simpler  than all.  You have to get height of your text  then apply constant value with  min(yourTextHeight,maximumHeight). Not related but for just curiosity  Which library you are using for calling and video calling

Comment: actually this screen shot is from whatsapp

Comment: @MidhunNarayan LOL no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
/// Orignal Height for Text View
var orignalHeight : CGFloat?

/// Height Constraint of Text View
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTVHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

/// In ViewDidLayoutSubviews Get Height
self.orignalHeight = self.descriptionTextView.frame.size.height

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        /// Get Width Which will be always same
        let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width

        /// Here we need to get The height as Greatest that we can have or expected
        textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

        /// Get New Size 
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

        /// New Frame
        var newFrame = textView.frame
        newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)

        /// Orignal height is height that is assigned to TextView for first time and 100 is maximum height that textview can increase 
        self.descriptionTVHeightConstraint.constant = min(100,max(Int(newFrame.size.height),Int(self.orignalHeight!))



        bookSessionStruct.sessionTopicDiscussion = textView.text!.trimmed()

    }
```

Comment: in this code where i will set my maximum height to 100 ?

Comment: I will recommend not to give maximum height there.  Let's just keep it with greatestFinestMagnitude. But can add new check in if else above for Max Height

Comment: @MidhunNarayan Check the edit        `self.descriptionTVHeightConstraint.constant = min(100,max(Int(newFrame.size.height),Int(self.orignalHeight!))` is the line you all need !!

Answer (score 0):

Set `UITextView`'s `isScrollEnabled` to false, then `UITextView` will fit it's size automatically.

And Remember do not add constraints for height anchor with a constant value:

```
textView.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in maker.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(xxx) }
```

Hope that helpful.

Comment: what is this snp property and what i need to import to get this ?

Comment: You should import [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit).   i just want tell you that if you set `isScrollEnabled ` to false, then you should not add any constraint for height because It can fit it's height automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Put the `UITextView` within another container view (Colour red here)and set the `constraints` of the containerview like the below mentioned image.

[image]

`UITextView` within the `containerview` will have `leading`  `trailing`  `top` `bottom` constraint aligned to the `containerview` (The red one) here.

after that you have to take the referencing outlet of the `height` constraint & `bottom` constraint of the containerview (Image provided below).

[image]

After that put the piece of code shown below in `viewDilLoad` method...

[image]

Then just write down the two method to control the rest of the things. And *Hola* ! you are a champion ! You have made it.

`//MARK: TextView delegate`

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(text == "\n") {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}


func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {


    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame = CGRect.init(x: newFrame.origin.x, y: newFrame.origin.y+newFrame.height-newSize.height, width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)

    let newHeight = newFrame.size.height as CGFloat

    Swift.print("height: %f",newHeight)

    if newHeight > 40 && newHeight <= 105
    {
        chatBoxContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight + 16
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    else if newHeight <= 40
    {
        chatBoxContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 56
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}


@objc func keyboardWillChangeFrame(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

        let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
        let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
        let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let endFrameY = endFrame?.origin.y ?? 0
        let tabbarHeight = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
        if (endFrameY >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height) {
            Swift.print("----< %f",endFrameY)
            self.bottomViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
        } else  {
            Swift.print("----> %f",endFrameY)
            self.bottomViewBottomConstraint.constant = -((endFrame?.size.height)!-tabbarHeight! )
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                       delay: TimeInterval(0),
                       options: animationCurve,
                       animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                       completion: nil)
    }
}
```